# How far to go in encapsulation?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

Is there a general consensus on how deep encapsulation should extend in C++? The specific example I am looking at is whether you should restrict access to vectors in a class. Should the vector be passed with `getVector()`, or should it be restricted to `getVectorItem(int i)` and `addVectorItem(int x)`?

```
public:
    vector<int>* getVector() const;
```

Where getVector returns a pointer the the vector

**Or**

```
public:
    int getVectorItem(int i) const;
```

Where `getVectorItem(i)` returns whatever `_vector[i]` is.

Do you catch my drift?

Comment: This question is too general.  What is the best (or, at least, a good) solution depends on the particular use-case at hand.

Comment: You would not be able to return a `vector<int>*` of the object's vector if the member function is const (unless with casting, so let's exclude that).

Comment: @5gon12eder - I see. I was wondering if there was a general consensus. In that case, I will do whatever fits best. Thanks.

Comment: @juanchopanza That would only work if the object also kept an owning pointer to the vector.

Comment: The question is not how far. The question is: Do you posses the constitution? The debt of faith... to go as far as is needed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on the use case it can be better to have a way to access members and modify them without exposing the underlying data. In your specific example it would mean the second option is the way to go.

```
public:
  int getItem(int index) const;
  void setItem(int index, int item);
```

If the underlying data structure changes you don't have to modify how the user accesses your wrapper. If you are returning more complex data then you can just return const references to make it clear how a user is supposed to access the data.

```
public:
  ComplexClass const& getItem(std::string const& key) const;
  void setItem(std::string const& key, ComplexClass const& item);
```

As before by having the public getters/setters you prevent a user from malforming the internal data the class has and allows you to implement any kind of protection.

As an example if a user is returned an array what's to stop them from editing the incorrect element?

```
class Foo
{
public:
  std::vector<int> & getContainer() { return container; }

private:
  std::vector<int> container;
};

Foo foo;
std::vector<int> vector = foo.getContainer(); 
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  vector.push_back(i);

vector[99999] = 0; // The program will crash here
```

With a custom wrapper though we prevent the crash

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() : container(10) {}

  int getItem(int index) const
  { 
    if(index >= container.size() || index < 0)
      return -1; // error case
    else
      return container[index];
  }

  void setItem(int index, int item) 
  {
    if(index < container.size() && index > 0)
      container[index] = item;
  }

private:
  std::vector<int> container;
};

Foo foo;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  foo.setItem(i, i);

foo.setItem(99999, 0); // Nothing happens
```

You can even add iterator operator overloads to make the accessing look exactly like accessing a vector. However if you are creating a wrapper around a container make sure to implement an iterable interface.

Answer (score 1):

Every different circumstance requires a different amount of encapsulation so giving a general answer to a general question is not possible.

What I might suggest you is just just make your vector containing class iterable directly, something like:

```
class Foo
{
  private:
    vector<int> data;

  public:
    typedef typename decltype(data)::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename decltype(data)::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return data.end(); }
    const_iterator begin() const ...
}
```

In this way you won't expose the internals of `Foo` but you will be able to use it in standard STL algorithms and such. Of course this works only if you have one data structure containing data, unless you take care of using a different naming scheme to retrieve the iterators.

Comment: That's a really interesting idea. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The `inline` is actually superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

The two aren't the same. The former allows a caller to resize the vector, for example, whereas the latter does not. So this is not a question of style but an actual design choice, and only you know how much of your class you want the outside world to be able to change.